# Get full artifact name generated by gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm publishing an artifact using `maven-publish`.

When I'm pushing a release artifact, the resulting artifact version is the same as the project version itself.  For example if gradle.properties has `version=1.2.3`, the artifact would be something like `foo-1.2.3.zip`.

When I run a SNAPSHOT publish, the resulting artifact will include additional information in the version.  For example `version=1.2.4-SNAPSHOT` gives `foo-1.2.4-20220427.094127-1.zip`.  The additional information would appear to be the time and date to avoid clashes, I assume.

Is there anyway I can access this full artifact name in my gradle scripts?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the artifact names explicitly like this for example

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId = 'library'
            version = '1.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Then gradle will use the defaults that are taken from your `build.gradle`, `gradle.properties` and the module directory names.

I'm not sure if there's a way to configure the mavenPublish plugin to print out the maven artifact upon publishing, but you can look in your `~/.m2` directory to see what exactly has been published to your local if you run `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

I'm also thinking you could create a custom task to print out the group, artifact and version, something like this in the `build.gradle` of your project you are publishing:

```
project.task('getMavenCoordinates') {
    doLast {
        println "Maven Artifact: ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"    
    }
}

project.task("publishToMavenLocal").dependsOn("getMavenCoordinates")
```

If you wanted to configure the task to run after a different maven-pubish task, just change it accordingly! But something like that could help achieve what you want.

Comment: The issue is that, in the case of SNAPSHOT, the version is different from the full artifact name.  As described in the original post, it's appended with the date/time i.e 20220427.094127